# How to integrate MuPDF 1.3 in iOS Project

Tags: ios, xcode, integrate, mupdf

There is build-in PDF render engine for iOS, but it doesn't solve the "Transparency Flattening" issue. Hence I try to integrate MuPDF 1.3 into project.
I tried to use reference the MuPDF project, and it failed.
Then I build debug static libraries for each architecture, and use "Library Search Paths" and "Other Link Flags" to separate the linked library while building binary of different architecture, but XCode keeps showing "Undefined symbols for architecture armxxx".
Finally, I built the release version static library of MuPDF, which should compatible for all architecture, and XCode still keeps showing same thing as before.
Does there anyone integrate and compile MuPDF 1.3 successfully? Please give me some hint.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I built the release version static library of MuPDF, and add it into the "Link Binary With Libraries" along with all third party requirement and "JavaScriptCore.framework".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer but it could help people a day or another.
As I had to integrate the MuPDF library into one of my (Swift) project, I generated
the static fat libraries and integrate them into Xcode.

Here you go with a step-by-step quick tutorial:

## How to build the static fat library:

1. git clone --recursive git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git
2. Go to `mupdf/platform/ios`
3. Open *MuPDF.xcodeproj* with Xcode.
4. Configure the scheme of the MuPDF target to *Release*.
5. Build and run the app on an iPhone simulator.

   - This will generate the library for platforms `i386` and `x86_64`
6. Build and Run the app on a real iPhone device - use your own bundle id, certificate and provisioning profile.

   - This will generate the library for platforms `armv7` and `arm64`
7. Go to `mupdf/build/`

   - You will find two folders that contains all built librairies: `release-ios-i386-x86_64` and `release-ios-armv7-arm64`
8. Now you need to create fat libraries with all 4 architectures for the mupdf one and all its dependencies.

`lipo -create ./*/libcurl.a -output 'libcurl.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libfreetype.a -output 'libfreetype.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libjbig2dec.a -output 'libjbig2dec.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libjpeg.a -output 'libjpeg.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libmujs.a -output 'libmujs.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libmupdf.a -output 'libmupdf.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libopenjpeg.a -output 'libopenjpeg.a' ; lipo -create ./*/libz.a -output 'libz.a'`

## How to integrate MuPDF into your project:

1. Add/import into your project:

   - All header files from `mupdf/include/mupdf`
   - All obj-c classes from `mupdf/platform/ios/`classes
   - The common.[h,m] files from `mupdf/platform/ios`
2. Add/import the previously generated fat libraries (8 files)
3. Configure the `Library Search Path` by adding the path to your library files.

   - For example `$(inherited) $(PROJECT_DIR)/External/MuPDF/lib/`

You should now be able to build and run your app with the library included.
Use the sample project to understand how the library works or any online tutorial.

## Pro Tip:

The final fat libraries are pretty big all together (~ 46mb).
You could easily reduce the final size of your app by importing:

1. Under a release folder just the lib.a from `mupdf/build/release-ios-armv7-arm64`
2. Under a debug folder the big generated fat librairies from `mupdf/build/`
3. Set different `Library Search Path` for `Debug` and `Release` config.

Once done, you will be able to **build and run on `Debug` on every simulator and devices. But only on devices for `Release`**. Which in the end you need as your app, through, the AppStore
should only run on real devices. There is no need to include debug-simulator architecture static librairies.

Here is a screenshot of all imported files into my Xcode project:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried importing it with cocoapods? The example above from Joseph seems nice but im trying it using Swift and I can't figure out how.

Comment: Hi, I actually did not have the time and Joseph released this pod after I still had to deal with MuPDF. 
PS: I integrated MuPDF within a Swift project and it worked/works :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to use the [MuPDF CocoaPod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MuPDF), which I just created. There is an [example application based on that pod](https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example).

Comment: When using this CocoaPod I'm still getting this error message "You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64" when running "pod install". I changed the bitcode setting but nothing has changed, still the same error... If you know what else could I try I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Tunerx I've just pushed a new version of the pod (1.8.1) that pulls in the 1.8 release of mupdf, this resolves that issue. (The example app my answer links to has been updated too and builds with bitcode now.)

Comment: @JosephH - does this library has support for swift?